# Running Flask application from virtual environment

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv, wsgi

I have a simple flask app that i want to be accessible from internet.
OS is debian7, and unfortunately it can't be changed.

What I did:
- downloaded and installed Python3.4 into /usr/local/opt/python3.4.3
- installed wsgi lib for py3
- installed virtualenv and created new env in my flask project folder
- installed flask together with some other packages that I need within this env
- created VirtualHost as follows:

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/Monitor
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
                ServerName {ip address}
                ServerAdmin {my email}
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Monitor/monitor.wsgi

                <Directory /var/www/Monitor/Monitor/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                Alias /static /var/www/Monitor/Monitor/static

                <Directory /var/www/Monitor/Monitor/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

now when i try to access the app from the internet I see these errors in error.log

```
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] /usr/local/bin/python3
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip] mod_wsgi (pid=13450): Target WSGI script '/var/www/Monitor/monitor.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip] mod_wsgi (pid=13450): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/Monitor/monitor.wsgi'.
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]   File "/var/www/Monitor/monitor.wsgi", line 21, in <module>
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]     from Monitor import app as application
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]   File "/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]     from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]   File "/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]     from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]   File "/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]     __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]   File "/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 113
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]     return u'<p>%s</p>' % escape(self.description)
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip]                       ^
[Sat Nov 14 22:16:04 2015] [error] [client ip] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From what I could find in the internet, such errors appear when trying to start flask app with python version <= 3.3, which is not my case I think (how do i check?)

here is my wsgi that starts the app

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import logging


logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

PROJECT_DIR = '/var/www/Monitor/'
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

def execfile(filename):
    globals = dict(__file__ = filename)
    exec(open(filename).read(), globals)


activate_this = '/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this)

from Monitor import app as application
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Any additional information will be supplied if necessary.

Comment: Which python version is installed as default python?

Comment: If that's python < 3.3, then there may be issues (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/python3/#requirements) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494104/from-flask-import-flask-throws-up-a-syntax-error-python

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup, define default python?

Comment: @palfrey, i mentioned it in my post

Comment: @ArseniyS.Ivanov You mentioned installing 3.4.3 in /usr/local/opt/python3.4.3 but what's /usr/local/bin/python3 ?

Comment: @palfrey, /usr/local/bin/python3 is an ls to python in my venv
`ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff    41 Nov 14 21:57 python3 -> /var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/bin/python3`

Comment: run `python -V` and/or `python3 -V` without `virtualenv`

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup, `#python -V
Python 2.7.3
#python3 -V
Python 3.4.3`

Comment: I've followed this article for Ubuntu and it worked fine...  Maybe you can see the differences in your approach. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks a lot, i will make sure to read it later, unfortunately I can't change from apache2 to nginx (although i would love to) on this server.

Comment: I'm sure there's a conversion sheet for the config somewhere. For example, this one goes from Apache2 to nginx, so just follow this one backwards   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 0):

Default Python3 on Debian 7 is 3.2.3, libapache2-mod-wsgi is in version 3.3.

You Apache run Your app with default Python because mod-wsgi has to be compiled against one and only one python version (in this case python 3.3).

### mod-wsgi 3.3

If You want to run only one app (or many apps) with Python 3.4, try to recompile mod-wsgi with python 3.4

### mod-wsgi 4.1.x or newer

This newer version of mod_wsgi provides a way of installing mod_wsgi against multiple Python versions and running up an Apache instance for each using a provided script. The script takes over all the setup of the Apache configuration so you do not need to worry about it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

### old answer

To change Python version, set in Apache conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/opt/python3.4.3/
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/Monitor:/var/www/Monitor/Monitor/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/usr/local/opt/python3.4.3/lib/site-packages
```

for details read https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome

Comment: Oh, wow, that certainly makes sense to try, I will try and let you know how this will go. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i tried.
what i did:
- created and edited the new file named activate_python_343.py in bin folder of venv, so it looks like this [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=i7CkdT3g)

- then i changed wsgi like so [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UU2Wc7tn):

when i access the page I see the same error as before - with werkzeug.exceptions [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QikgvDj8)

Comment: does this mean the app still tries to use the wrong python version?

Comment: I see my big mistake. You cannot change Python version from python script. I update my answer.

Comment: i did try that already, when I do that i get non-stop errors in error.log about encodings like so:
`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named encodings`

Comment: thanks for keep helping me with this issue. I changed the values as you said, now apache2 wont start with an error `Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/Monitor:
WSGIPythonPath takes one argument, Python module search path.`

Comment: nevermind, i made a typo in a path variable, now fixed it and even with both Home and Path ended up with the same error about local encoding and absence of encoding module.

Comment: my entire /etc/apache2/sites-available/Monitor file looks like so: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sxFKsjKV)

Comment: On the internet I've seen two other theories - one about permissions and another about mod_wsgi being compiled for the wrong version of python. Does any of that sound like a valid thing to check? If so, how would i go about it? Sorry for such a noob questions, really new to all this.

Comment: I'm don't use apache. I prefer supervisor+gunicorn+nginx, but I like to improve my knowledge. I update answer.

Comment: thanks for you answers, I will try to recompile the mod_wsgi for P3.4.3.

Comment: ended up doing this:
- pip-installed mod_wsgi into venv (for that i had to recompile python with "--enable-shared" flag)
- disabled default apache2 wsgi (a2dismod wsgi) and removed Monitor file from sites-available
- started the server with mod_wsgi-express command
(env-related mod_wsgi usage described [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi))